# How approve call logs and sms permissions app form google

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I have a application like sms and call log manager. so i use call log and read sms permissions, but google play reject my
 app. please hep me to fix this issue and suggest me which option will best .

1. Default SMS handler
2. Default Phone handler
3. Default Assistant handler
4. Transactional backup and restore for users and archive for enterprise (time-limited/non-continuous)
5. Enterprise SMS call archives
6. Caller ID, spam detection, and blocking
7. Connected device companion apps (for example, smartwatch or automotive)
8. Cross-device synchronization or transfer of SMS or calls
9. SMS-based financial transactions and related activity where access is restricted to financial SMS transactions (for example, 5-digit messages)
10. SMS based money management
11. Proxy calls
12. Services - Carrier
13. Device Automation
14. Physical safety/emergency alert apps (e.g., senior safety)
15. Call-based OTP account verification
16. Using SMS_CB_RECEIVED for customer communications (e.g., Smart Zone Cast service)
17. Write and Show Call History in Dialer
18. In-vehicle hands-free use or projected display

Answer (score 0):

I you are using these permissons for backup then you can use
 1. Default SMS handler
 2. Transactional backup and restore for users and archive for enterprise (time-limited/non-continuous)

And also need to mentions in Privacy Policy and Descriptions of the app.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/default-handlers